# New to Java, trying to make a basic program but running into problems

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a basic calculation program using user input (pretty much just my own) and handling very minimal calculations. I can't seem to get the calculation to return though. I'm doing all of my calculations in this file:

```
public class Drug {

private double goalForQuarter = 3716.0;
private double currentScripts;
private double currentDaysIntoQuarter;
private double scriptsNeededDaily100 = goalForQuarter / currentDaysIntoQuarter;
private double scriptsNeededDaily105 = scriptsNeededDaily100 * 1.05;
private double scriptPercentage = currentScripts / scriptsNeededDaily100;


public Drug () {

}

public Drug (double currentScripts) {
    this.currentScripts = currentScripts;
}

public Drug (double currentScripts, double currentDays){
    this.currentScripts = currentScripts;
    this.currentDaysIntoQuarter = currentDays;
}

public double calcDrug100 (){

    return this.scriptPercentage;
}


}
```

This main program is run here:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input number of days into Quarter: ");
        double days = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Input current number of Scripts: ");
        double scripts = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());


        Drug drug1 = new Drug(scripts, days);

        System.out.println(drug1.calcDrug100());

    }

}
```

Even with the user input, I'm printing out 0.0 regardless. I've played with my variables and methods but can't seem to make it work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

`scriptPercentage` is a field. It doesn't automatically update when `currentScripts` or `scriptsNeededDaily100` do.

```
public double calcDrug100 (){
    this.scriptPercentage = this.currentScripts / this.scriptsNeededDaily100;
    return this.scriptPercentage;
}
```

Comment: Even with this correction I'm still returning 0.0. Am I missing something in addition

Comment: What numbers are you entering?

Comment: days : 16
scripts : 567, the program runs as so: Input number of days into Quarter: 16
Input current number of Scripts: 
567
0.0

Comment: In the constructor you are using `this.currentDaysIntoQuarter = currentDays;`

Comment: scriptsNeededDaily100  needs to be initialized inside constructor, otherwise Robert's solution won't work

Comment: That fixed it Ajay Deshwal! Thank you all for the help! I put in the wrong name earlier :)

Comment: Glad that helped. Cheers!